# Windows search for all filenames having "string1" in the contents and not having "dislike" in the contents

Tags: windows, powershell, search, full-text-search, file-search

Below windows powershell command helps list all files [excluding a few filenames] that contain `string1`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Jenkins" -File -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike "*log*" -and $_.DirectoryName -notlike "*\\Backup\\*" } | Select-String -Pattern "string1"
```

I wish to enhance this command so it displays all files containing `string1` but should not contain the string `dislike`.

Can you please suggest?

Comment: As an aside: do not use ``\\`` in your wildcard expression: ``\`` never has special meaning to PowerShell. E.g., `'...\backup\...' -notlike '*\\Backup\\*'` is `$true`, which is not your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) does *not* support *combining* positive and negative matching - you can use *either* positive matching (by default) *or* negative matching (with `-NotMatch`).

The simplest solution - which assumes that each file fits into memory in full (usually a safe bet for *text* files) - is to read each file into memory *in full* with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Raw` switch and use `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) and its *negating variant* (`-notmatch`):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath D:\Jenkins -File -Recurse | 
  Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -notlike '*log*' -and 
    $_.DirectoryName -notlike '*\Backup\*' -and
    (
      ($content = $_ | Get-Content -Raw) -match 'string1' -and 
      $content -notmatch 'dislike'
    )
  }
```

If you do run out of memory,<sup>[1]</sup> combine two `Select-String` calls as follows:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath D:\Jenkins -File -Recurse | 
  Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -notlike '*log*' -and 
    $_.DirectoryName -notlike '*\Backup\*' -and
    (
      ($_ | Select-String -Quiet 'string1') -and 
      -not ($_ | Select-String -Quiet 'dislike')
    )
  }
```

If you don't mind using an advanced [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), a *single* `Select-String` call is sufficient:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath D:\Jenkins -File -Recurse | 
  Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -notlike '*log*' -and 
    $_.DirectoryName -notlike '*\Backup\*' -and
    (
      $_ | Select-String -Quiet '(?s)(?<!dislike.*?)string1(?!.*?dislike)'
    )
  }
```

For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/7RkjS9/1).

---

<sup>[1] Given that *text* files are rarely so large that they wouldn't fit into memory, a potential way to avoid the out-of-memory problems is to restrict the files to search through to text files only, *via their filename extensions*, if feasible; e.g., you could add `-Include *.txt, *.csv, ...` to the `Get-ChildItem` call.</sup>